# How to use maybe in a list in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I am using haskell and the following:

```
convertToBasis :: [String] -> Maybe [Basis]
convertToBasis [] = Nothing
convertToBasis (h:t) = basis : convertToBasis t
    where 
        basis = toCandidateBasis h
```

Returns a type of [Maybe Basis] I want a type of Maybe [Basis]
toCandidateBasis is shown below:

```
toCandidateBasis :: String -> Maybe Basis
toCandidateBasis myStr = if not $ has7UniqueLetters myStr [] then
    Nothing
    else
        Just (dedupAndSort myStr)
```

The function returns nothing if a String does not have 7 unique characters otherwise it removes duplicates and sorts the String alphabetically and return that result. Now the return type of the function is Maybe Basis. Hence when I when I get a list of strings and want to convert them to their respective candidate basises one by one, it will concat all the maybes and return me a type of:

```
[Maybe Basis]
```

But I want a type of

```
Maybe [Basis]
```

It should return Nothing only when the given Basis array is empty otherwise return some result. How do I do this?

Comment: "return Nothing only when the given Basis array is empty" Buy why? If `Just []` is impossible, then there's no point in returning a Maybe at all. "non-empty list or nothing" conveys the same values as "possibly-empty list".

Comment: Because if you have lets say a list of ["IS String", [], "String"] you want to return ["IS String", "String"] not the original thing back.

Comment: I don't see any Maybes in that example. And it's easy to turn the former into the latter without messing with Maybe: `filter (not . null)`.

Answer (score 3):

There's really no reason to use a `Maybe [a]` unless there is a semantic difference between `Nothing` and `Just []`, which it sounds like there is not in your case. However, it is a fairly common use case to reduce a list `[Maybe a]` to a list `[a]` by removing all the `Nothing`s— so common, in fact, that there's a builtin function for doing that: [`catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.17.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes).

Comment: `toCandidateBasis = traverse convertToBasis` is also a definition of a reasonable alternative thing to want here.

Comment: @amalloy Do you mean `convertToBasis = traverse toCandidateBasis`? It doesn't work the other way.

Comment: Oh, of course. I copied the wrong names.

Comment: But if I tried to use a head operation on Maybe [a] it will complain stating that Couldn't match expected type: [Maybe Basis]
              with actual type: Maybe [Basis]

Comment: You can't call `head :: [a] -> a` on something of type `Maybe [a]` because `Maybe [a]` is not `[a]`.

Comment: @chen that's why everyone is saying you should use `[Basis]` instead of `Maybe [Basis]`